# How do I convert ubuntu 16.04 / partition from a standard partition to LVM?

Tags: lvm

How do I convert ubuntu 16.04 / partition from a standard partition to LVM ?

Comment: Not enought details to help you, please provide your current partition mapping with, for each partition, the space left on it.

Comment: 1. create logical volume, then 2. copy partition content to logical volume. If the partition contains the root filesystem, I would reinstall.